# Azure AD Graph Request in WebAPI2

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Recently created WebAPI2 web-service to get list of all active Directory Applications and User. on Local IIS List of Application and Users will be fetched using Azure AD Graph API without any problem.

When deploy webAPI2 on Azure as a resource. List of Users will be fetched as expected but list of Application which is fetched using following code throws error.

Call to get List of Applications:

```
IPagedCollection<IApplication> applications= await activeDirectoryClient.Applications.ExecuteAsync();
```

Error Stack

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: type
>      at Microsoft.Data.Edm.EdmUtil.CheckArgumentNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Edm.EdmTypeSemantics.AsComplex(IEdmTypeReference type)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ReadNonEntityValueImplementation(String payloadTypeName, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, CollectionWithoutExpectedTypeValidator collectionValidator, Boolean validateNullValue, Boolean isTopLevelPropertyValue, Boolean insideComplexValue, String propertyName, Boolean readRawValueEvenIfNoTypeFound)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadOpenProperty(IODataJsonLightReaderEntryState entryState, String propertyName, Boolean propertyWithValue)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadUndeclaredProperty(IODataJsonLightReaderEntryState entryState, String propertyName, Boolean propertyWithValue)
>      at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadEntryPropertyWithValue(IODataJsonLightReaderEntryState entryState, String propertyName)

Application Flow:

> My Web Application Let say A call WebAPI B to get list of Users and Applications. Application type of webAPI is native and i'm using UserPasswordCredential and AcquireTokenAsync to get access token.

Comment: Woah... Have you tried calling the API manually with the access token you acquired for the client?

Comment: @juunas yes manually its working fine. Even on my local IIS its working fine. But when upload WebAPI on Azure then this issue happens for list of applications. I also updated the question with application flow.

Comment: @juunas I just deployed this webApi on another .net hosting environment. Its working fine. In this hosting environment we have dedicated virtual machine and IIS. But we need to deploy this WebAPI on Azure.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @umer I failed with the same error, did you solve this problem?

Comment: @HaibaraAi No, still failed to resolve this issue. The only thing work for me is to change the WebAPI deploying technique. Previously i was deploying WebAPI on Azure as PAAS(Creating service on Azure portal and uploading using filezila). So, now I deployed it directly on IIS of Azure Virtual Machine using remote desktop.

Comment: @umer I have this issue in production envrionment by customer in feb 14, and he operate this in feb 13 09:19 successful, but my develop envrionment can get Applications correctly now.

Comment: @HaibaraAi what about your production environment now. can u get applications??

Comment: @umer I don't know yet, I don't have enough permissions to operate the production environment. I have to wait for customer operation. and I don't know if it's my  problem or Azure's problem.

Comment: @umer Have you tried to get applications again recently?

Comment: @umer a Web API cannot be a native application (it needs to be a confidential client application). Also you are not supposed to use username password in a Web API (and this has limitations, for instance if the tenant admin has set conditional access). Can't you use https://aka.ms/msal-net-on-behalf-of ?

Comment: @HaibaraAi currently I deployed application on Azure Virtual Machine's IIS and its working fine there so i didn't try to debug this issues further. How do u deploy application on production?You are using Azure Virtual Machine??

Comment: @Jean-MarcPrieur Thanks for your concern. Actually our application has a very complex architecture and this solution fit best for our scenario. Before implementation, this solution was also discussed with a Microsoft team.They approved it. But yes there is always risk of security and limitations.

Comment: @umer I deployed webapi in appservice.

Comment: @HaibaraAi same issue with me if deployed as appservice using azure portal. But no issue if deployed on azure Virtual machine. Better to report this issue to Microsfoft team.

Comment: @umer Good news, Get Applications is ok for production environment now by customer, I don't think I made any changes. Maybe there's only that day when there's the issue.

Comment: @HaibaraAi Good to hear that. i'll give it a try later this week. Lets hope this issue never comes again :)

Comment: @HaibaraAi I published WebAPI on azure and this time it works like a charm. I guess this was issue on Microsoft side and they fixed it,Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue (Microsoft.Data.Edm.EdmUtil.CheckArgumentNull[...) from time to time when publishing something that has nothing to do with Azure. I guess this is a compilation problem (sometimes it works, sometimes not :-))... clean and publish do the job (unfortunatly)